# What is collaboration tools in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint

Please give me know what is collaboration tools in SharePoint 2010?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Collaboration tools in SharePoint 2010:

1. Discussion Board
2. Blog
3. Wiki
4. Tagging
5. Bookmarking
6. Rating.
7. Activity feeds